# What return if FileContentResult is null

Tags: asp.net

I have method, that return FileContentResult:

```
    public FileContentResult fileStream(string EAN)
    {
        //Finding byte[] of PDF
        byte[] pdf = findPDF(EAN);

        return new FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf");
    }
```

And I use it in iframe:

```
<iframe src="@Url.Action("fileStream", "Approve", new { EAN = Model.ID_EAN })" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

What should I return if pdf is null (FileContentResult is null). Now it shows Error page with controller name and controller action.

Comment: "what should I return" it depends what do you want to do

Comment: I want to return something like message "This PDF not found"

Comment: Try returning a `HttpNotFoundResult`

Comment: Please add you solution as an answer, not as an edit to your question, to learn more how SO works see [tour]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've changed  return value of my method to ActionResult and returned new HttpNotFoundResult();

```
    public ActionResult fileStream(string EAN)
    {
        //Hledani byte[] pdf
        byte[] pdf = findPDF(EAN);

        if (pdf == null)
            return new HttpNotFoundResult();

        return new FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf");
    }
```